# Creating a new header in docx4j

Tags: java

I have a maven project with docx4j. I have managed to successfully convert html file to docx. However I'm interested into inserting a header to the docx file.

In github docx4j there is a sample ([link](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/HeaderFooterCreate.java)) which I used the it worked as expected, i.e.

```
Relationship relationship = createHeaderPart(wordMLPackage);



public static Relationship createHeaderPart(
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage)
            throws Exception {
        
    HeaderPart headerPart = new HeaderPart();
    Relationship rel =  wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart()
            .addTargetPart(headerPart);
    
    // After addTargetPart, so image can be added properly
    headerPart.setJaxbElement(getHdr(wordprocessingMLPackage, headerPart));

    return rel;
}

public static Hdr getHdr(WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage,
            Part sourcePart) throws Exception {

    Hdr hdr = objectFactory.createHdr();
    
    // I modified it for simplicity
    P headerParagraph = docx.getMainDocumentPart().createParagraphOfText("hi there");
    hdr.getContent().add(headerParagraph);

    return hdr;

}
```

This is working as expected

However I'm interested into using dynamic content from html so I used:

```
public static Hdr getHdr(WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage,
            Part sourcePart) throws Exception {

    Hdr hdr = objectFactory.createHdr();
    
    String html = "<html><body><p>hi there</p></body></html>";
    XHTMLImporter XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordprocessingMLPackage);
    hdr.getContent().add(XHTMLImporter.convert(html, null));
    
    return hdr;
}
```

This doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that XHTMLImporter is creating a list of objects, i.e.

```
public static Hdr getHdr(WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage,
            Part sourcePart) throws Exception {

    Hdr hdr = objectFactory.createHdr();
    
    String html = "<html><body><p>hi there</p></body></html>";
    XHTMLImporter XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordprocessingMLPackage);
    List<Object> list = XHTMLImporter.convert(html, null);
    hdr.getContent().add(list.get(0));
    
    return hdr;
}
```